# Using declaration compiles in gcc and msvc but rejected in clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I have written the following program to clear my `using declaration` concept. But surprisingly, the code compiles with gcc and msvc but rejected by clang.

```
namespace X 
{ 
    struct type {}; 
}
namespace Y 
{ 
    using type = int; 
}
using X::type;
using Y::type;
int main()
{
    auto i = sizeof(type); //gcc and msvc accepts this but clang rejects this
}
```

[Check Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Tsx54ro5)

As you can see the above program compiles with gcc and msvc but clang says:

```
<source>:13:21: error: reference to 'type' is ambiguous
    auto i = sizeof(type); 
                    ^
<source>:10:10: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'type'
using Y::type;
         ^
<source>:9:10: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'type'
using X::type;
         ^
<source>:13:21: error: reference to 'type' is ambiguous
    auto i = sizeof(type); 
                    ^
<source>:10:10: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'type'
using Y::type;
         ^
<source>:9:10: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'type'
using X::type;
         ^
```

My question is what is the correct behavior according to the standard. Which is the right compiler here.

Comment: Looks like all compilers are wrong. Gcc and msvc are wrong since they accept the invalid code. While clang rejects the code but for different reason. The program seems ill-formed.

Comment: This looks similar to https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/36 **Additional notes (January, 2005)**, which was resolved by P1787R6 as DR, and P1787R6 looks favoring MSVC/GCC behavior.

Comment: http://wg21.link/p1787: Richard’s proposal for “using-declarations & {,!}export” is followed: a (non-dependent) using-declaration is replaced with its referent(s) during name lookup rather than introducing additional declarations.

Answer (score 4):

##### Pre C++23

The program is **ill-formed**(see [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109621)) because a `using-declaration` is a **declaration** and so it must follow the rule of a declaration. In particular, the two given `using-declaration`s **declares** a type named `type`(*in the global namespace*) that refers to two different types `X::type` and `Y::type=int` .

Next, there cannot be more than one type declaration(in the same scope) with the same name **that refers to two different types**. This is explained in more detail below using the c++ standard:

Also from [using declaration's documentation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.udecl#12):

> Since a using-declaration is a declaration, **the restrictions on declarations of the same name in the same declarative region also apply to using-declarations**.

(emphasis mine)

Next, [basic.scope.declarative](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope#declarative-4) prevents declarations of same name that refers to two different types(which is the case in your example):

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> - **they shall all refer to the same entity**, or all refer to functions and function templates; or
> - exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name and the other declarations shall all refer to the same variable, non-static data member, or enumerator, or all refer to functions and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden ([basic.scope.hiding]).

(emphasis mine)

And since `type` refers to 2 different entities, the program is **ill-formed**.

---

##### Testing the above conclusion

Also note that besides the above quoted reference you can also test the above conclusion by replacing `using type = int;` with `struct type{};` in namespace `Y` and you'll notice that we get the expected error. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cP7xMP8nd):

```
namespace X 
{ 
     struct type{};
}
namespace Y 
{ 
    struct type{};  
}
using X::type;
using Y::type;      //NOT ALLOWED since same name "type" refers to different structs
```

Furthermore, if you change the above program to define `type` to be same type say as `int` then program will work since this time name refers to same type `int`. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/efM1q7EMW)

```
namespace X 
{ 
     using type= int ; 
}
namespace Y 
{ 
    using type= int;  
}
using X::type;
using Y::type;       //ALLOWED since "type" refer to same type int
```

Here is the gcc bug:

[GCC accepts invalid program with multiple using declarations](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109621)

---

##### C++23

The program is also **ill-formed** in C++23 but now due to the statement `auto i = sizeof(type);` instead of `using Y::type;`.

From C++23's *[namespace.udecl]*:

> If a declaration named by a using-declaration that inhabits the target scope of another declaration potentially
> conflicts with it (6.4.1), and either is reachable from the other, the program is ill-formed. **If two declarations
> named by using-declarations that inhabit the same scope potentially conflict, either is reachable from the
> other, and they do not both declare functions or function templates, the program is ill-formed.**
>
> [Note 4 : Overload resolution possibly cannot distinguish between conflicting function declarations. — end note]

(emphasis mine)

Comment: [`[basic.scope.declarative]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope#declarative-4.2) seems to be what "prevents declarations of same name that refers to two different types". Not `[basic.scope.hiding]`.

Comment: @Nelfeal Update the reference and made that more clear.

Comment: *updated (a typo in last comment)

Comment: See my comments under the question

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I've updated my answer(now in 2 parts) according to http://wg21.link/p1787, see if makes sense. I can rollback the edit if there is a mistake.

Comment: See http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#4.sentence-2 (applied after http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#3.sentence-2). The declaration of `X::type` is discarded because of `Y::type`. This replacement does not count as search in the corresponding namespaces following using-directives, which is what your quote is about. It refers to http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#2.2

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I see so this means that in c++23 OP's program is well-formed and is equivalent to [this modified program](https://godbolt.org/z/hh9TnP5do) right? Also what about [namespace.udir#6] that i quoted from c++23, doesn't that contradict basic.lookup.general#3 here. I guess since the declaration for the class is already discarded so [namespace.udir#6] doesn't apply since name lookup now finds only one declaration.

Comment: ...so there is no ambiguity and program is well-formed.

Comment: I'll ask Davis about the interaction of [namespace.udir]/6 with http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#4.sentence-2

Comment: Kk, the correct answer is in https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/302, I've fucked up with http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#def:potentially_conflict definition

Answer (score 1):

It seems the both compilers, gcc and msvc, have a bug.

The name `type` is redeclared in the global namespace with different meanings.

From the C++20 Standard (9.9 The using declaration)

> 12 Since a using-declaration is a declaration, the restrictions on
> declarations of the same name in the same declarative region (6.4)
> also apply to using-declarations.

and (6.4.1 Declarative regions and scopes)

> 4 Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
> which specifies the same unqualified name,

(4.2) — exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name **that is not a typedef name** and the other declarations shall all refer to the same variable, non-static data member, or enumerator, or all refer to functions and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden (6.4.10).